# Signing a certification request

Tags: wcf, ssl, certificate

I hope you are doing great,

I have a question, I was wondering if it's possible to sign a CSR created with IIS, with my own CA certificate, but this one does't have any private key.

Actually I am trying to secure my WCF service with certificate authentication, and now I am configuring the IIS, to do the validations with a specific athority.

Thnks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, the first step in generating a certificate is to generate a private key that the server uses to authenticate its identity. If you don't have any private keys, authentication becomes a problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if it's possible to sign a CSR created with IIS

Sure.

> , with my own CA certificate,

Sure.

> but this one does't have any private key.

No, you can't create the signature from the CA without having the CA's private key.  Otherwise there'd be no point to signatures.